# R Shiny app: showing multiple levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am building a shiny app which should make it possible to compare football (soccer for our USA friends) players on various statistics (passes, shots, goals etc.)

In the app it is possible to select one or multiple players and see how wel they preform on the statistics. However in my app the selecting of players is not working well in the creation of the plot. Sometimes it works, most of the time it shows an empty plot. If no player is selected it works well, the same for one player. The things breaks down on various occasions when more than 1 player is selected. Anyone knows whats up? Thanks!

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

dataset <- data.frame(player=c("Joel", "Marty", "Tinus", "Jelle","Gio","Tom",
                              "Tim","Peter","Marco", "Martin"), 
                  pass=c(1,10,30,50,80,200,250,300,500,2000),
                  goals=c(12,10,8,1,3,5,9,7,2,17))

fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Player"),

  sidebarPanel(


    selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[3]]),
    selectInput('z','Player', levels(dataset$player), multiple=TRUE)
),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot')
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


function(input, output) {
  dataset<-data.frame(player=c("Joel", "Marty", "Tinus", "Jelle", "Gio","Tom",
                               "Tim","Peter","Marco", "Martin"), 
                  pass=c(1,10,30,50,80,200,250,300,500,2000),
                  goals=c(12,10,8,1,3,5,9,7,2,17))


  dataset1<-reactive({
    y<-input$y
data<-dataset 

if (!is.null(input$z) && input$z != "") {
  data <- filter(data, player == input$z)
} 
data
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

   ggplot(dataset1(), aes_string(x=dataset1()$player, y=input$y))+
   geom_bar(stat="identity")

  }, height=700) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your code :

1) `player == input$z` cant work when `length(input$z)>1`  you need to use `%in%` like `data <- filter(data, player %in% input$z)`

2) `x=dataset1()$player` print smthing strange in `aes_string` you need `x="player"`